# Как в socket.io получить request клиента?

Tags: node.js, сокет, socket.io, request

Как в socket.io получить request клиента (то бишь тот объект, что при рендере отдает сервер клиенту)?

```
 io.on('connection', function (socket) {
     console.log(socket); // тут можно получить как-либо request ?
     ...
 });
```

Comment: впервые слышу про какой-то реквест в сокет-ио. вы не путаете с HTTP? socket.io просто устанавливает соединение, всё остальное надо посылать ручками. вы можете только айпишник получить от клиента.

Answer (score 1):

Передавайте в куки id сессии, сохраняйте в таблицу юзера и доставайте из таблицы инфу о нем.

Comment: Что-то не похоже, чтобы это было ответом на заданный вопрос...

Comment: Я так понимаю стоял вопрос о том, как выловить инфу о юзере в сокет соединении, часто задавая данный вопрос юзер ожидает получить именно данные для сокет авторизации ...

Comment: А я понял так: "как на странице получать данные, передаваемые с сервера через сокет-соединение?" :)

Answer (score 0):

В io нет такого понятия как реквест ресвонс. io немного более низкого уровня протокол, в нем есть просто сообщения. после того как ты установил соединение ты можешь отправлять сообщения с помощью

```
socket.emit('event', { my: 'data' });
```

и ловить сообщения с помощью

```
socket.on('event', function (data) {console.log(data);});
```

это можно делать в двухстороннем порядке как с сервера на клиент так и с клиента на сервер.